# Cannot play video, android 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, video, omnirom

Well hello,

I have a really troublesome and strange problem. Point is, I cannot play any video. Litterally NONE. Any type of video presented in ANY app cannot play, including advertisements.
Running Android 4.4.4 omnirom, but as it doesn't appear in the omnirom bugs my guess is I did something wrong in my system: Have developer rights, so anything could have gone wrong.
Any thoughts on this?
Preferably not directly call 'factory reset' ^^

UPDATE: Well, ok, I was wrong, it was a bug in Omnirom: On an older version of Omnirom it worked 'fine' (with it's own bugs, but still). Probably going to try another ROM in the near future, maybe something more stable.
At least thanks for your time everybody who gave ideas! :)

Comment: What does it say when you were trying to play a video?

Comment: What phone do you have? It sounds like you already realised a bug in the custom ROM is the most likely explanation.

Comment: It says nothing, it just shows the animation that it's loading, and depending on the app, after a while it gives a timeout giving you the option to retry.
My phone is the Note 2 of Samsung, but I was trying to imply a bug would be least likely, as the problem persists for multiple weeks now and there are no such bugs filed for Omnirom... I think me having changed some setting which enables or disables videos is more likely, but I am really unexperienced with this kind of problems.

Comment: I'd try another ROM, or restore a backup. I've used stable Omnirom on a few devices and some of them did have big bugs (generally it's great, and I'm not trying to put the devs down). Try restoring your last nandroid see if that works, then you can always restor a nandroid of Omnirom at a later point. Or try another ROM altogether.